# Java stream alternative to LambdaJ index

Tags: java, java-stream, lambdaj

What is Java stream API alternative to LambdaJ indexing? Let's say I have code like this

```
List<Product> products = ...
Map<Month, Product> productsOnMonths = Lambda.index(products, Lambda.on(Product.class).getMonth());
```

Where I know that every product has unique month attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 products.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getMonth, s -> s));
```

The difference here is that [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) can take a third argument that says how to merge two entries when they are the same; I don't think lambdaj offers that

Comment: Very elegant. Finally I used a version with identity function. `products.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getMonth, Function.identity()));`